# how to limit the rows adding in JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtextfield

I have a few text fields, A `JTable` and a `Button` (ADD).

Now, every time the button it gets the `JTextField`s data and adds a row in `JTable`.
And it adds the unlimited number of rows. I want to add only `10` rows.

```
public void setItemDetailInTable() {
    String free = freetext.getText();
    Object row[] = new Object[20];


    row[0] = itemcombo.getSelectedItem().toString();
    row[1] = mfgtext.getText();
    row[2] = sachsntext.getText();
    if (free.isEmpty()) {
        row[3] = qtytext.getText();
    } else {
        row[3] = qtytext.getText() + "+" + freetext.getText();
    }
    row[4] = pricetext.getText();
    row[5] = taxtext.getText() ;
    row[6] = discounttext.getText() ;
    row[7] = total.getText();

    model_table.addRow(row);
}
```

Comment: Please be aware of the Java naming convention. You have a variable called `model_table`. Variable names should be camelCase, which would be `modelTable`. Also try to make your types as specific as possible. If you know that `row` will only contain `String`s, declare it as `String row[]`. Which brings me to the next point.. Why does `row` have the size 20? You never fill those all 20 places in the array..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay, I got it..

```
if (table.getRowCount > 10){
    model_table.setRowCount(10)
}
```

Comment: What about `if(table.getRowCount) > 10) { return }` ?

Comment: return what.. ?

Comment: @KaranMalhotra if the methods return type is `void`, you don't can just `return`

Comment: @KaranMalhotra Since your return type is void, just leave it at "return", you will then jump out of the function and give control back to the caller

Answer (score 0):

Just add a counter ?

```
if (table.getRowCount < 10) {
     //doStuff...
} else {
    //doSomethingElse...
}
```

Comment: well, its simple that it require a decision statement... but what to put in doStuff ?

Comment: *"but what to put in doStuff ?"* One thing you might do is pop a dialog or change a label text to inform the user the table is full, then disable the text fields and either the button or its `Action`. Have a go at doing that, then if you hit a problem, post a [mcve].